# CSV Vs XML, Which one is efficient to store data

Tags: java, xml, database, csv

as i have not much knowledge & experience in Database and i have to use`xml or csv` for storing the data as DB. please let me know which one should i prefer?

There is `table : layout`

```
colomn : 3
          session-id : (user-id will be used on later stage)
          project-name : ( string type )
          upload-folder : string type (optional, it can be null)
```

A `session-id`(user id) can have many `project-name` but the name should be unique for one session id but another `session-id` may have the same `project-name`.

`upload-folder` is optional (can be null)

Ex.

```
 tavle : myTable

   session-id  |  project-name |  upload-folder |
--------------------------------------------------
      01A      |  myProject    |   upload-1
-------------------------------------------------
      01A      |  yourProj     |   upload-2
-------------------------------------------------
      02B      |  myProject    |   upload-1
-------------------------------------------------
      03C      |  myProject    |   upload-3
-------------------------------------------------
```

***please tell me, which one would be the better choice for this requirement***

Comment: CSV is almost never a better choice. Use XML, JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 4):

If your data is tabular, and not hierarchical, you have full control over both the import and export, and you will not wish to extend it later on, then CSV will be more efficient in filesize (and also parsing, probably).

Otherwise, you will be better off using XML

Answer (score 1):

CSV is easier to load and more efficient spacewise, but XML is easier for humans to read and there are many parsers available that make manipulating it easy.

For your data, I would go with CSV, unless you are sharing it with another person or group who don't know anything about the data.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is a lot more compact than XML, but XML is much more flexible than CSV.  If your data is at all complex (eg, if it has a column that can contain an arbitrary number of items), go with XML.

But you should also consider the JSON and YAML formats.  Both are reasonably space-efficient, and both have a lot of flexibility for handling complex data.  I tend to use JSON a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be tabular and have fixed number of columns, so CSV might be better choice for you. Reading and writing CSV is straightforward easy from most languages. If you have a huge amount of data, say gigabytes, then most space efficient is CSV.

If your data is hierarchical, or complex, then you should go for XML or JSON or even YAML. JSON has got lot of attention these days, and parser is available in any language.